# Expected Value of the F Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Stuck on this problem from my Econometrics homework, would appreciate some help!

---

Given the equation of the $F$ random variable $F = \frac{(X_1/k_1)}{(X_2/k_2)}$, show that:

$E(F) = E\left(\frac{1}{(X_2/k_2)}\right)$,

Can you conclude that $E(F) = 1$?

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbTge.jpg

Comment: Can you please write the definition of the $F$ random variable from equation B.43? What is $X_1, X_2, k_1, k_2$ etc.? You are at the risk of being down-voted for not supplying all the details and your own ideas/thoughts.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qEP3tMz.png

Comment: First use the independence; Second use the result from Chi-Square distribution to arrive the result of first part. For the next part apply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @BGM: For me anyhow, without elaboration, this Comment does not seem helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independently chi-squared with degrees of
freedom $k_1$ and $K_2,$ respectively.  Then $F$ has Snedecor's F-distribution
with $k_1$ and $k_2$ degrees of freedom. Wikipedia on 'F distribution' says
that $E(F) = k_2/(k_2 - 2),$ for $k_2 > 2.$ So, "not exactly."

The F-statistic (or "variance ratio" statistic) $F = S_1^2/S_2^2,$ where
$S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$ are variances of independent samples from
two normal populations, is often used to test whether the population
variances are equal ($H_0: \sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2$) or not
($H_a: \sigma_1^2 \ne \sigma_2^2$). In that context, one often
says, roughly, that $H_0$ is true if $S_1^2/S_2^2 \approx 1.$
But that is different from saying that $E(F) = 1$ under $H_0.$

If you have something else in mind, please edit your Question.

---

*Reality check:* A brief simulation in R statistical software with a million
realizations of $Q_1 \sim Chisq(10)$ and independently $Q_2 \sim Chisq(8):$

```
m = 10^6;  k1 = 10;  k2 = 8
q1 = rchisq(m, k1);  q2 = rchisq(m, k2)
f = (q1/k1)/(q2/k2)
mean(f)
## 1.334032  # aprx E(F) = 1.3333
k2/(k2-2)
## 1.333333

mean(1/(q2/k2))
## 1.333556
```

This illustrates the Wikipedia formula for $E(F)$. Just from the simulation,
it does seem that $E[1/(Q_2/k_2)]$ is the same. But, under my interpretation of your question, I do not see
a reasonable scenario in which these means would be exactly unity.
(Yes, *close to* 1 for very large $k_2$, but not exactly 1.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem (EX 11.(iv) in Wooldridge Introductory econometrics (7e)) is as follows:

Random variable
$$F = \frac{X_{1}/k_{1}}{X_{2}/k_{2}}$$
has F distribution where $X_{1} \sim \chi^2_{k1}$ and $X_{2} \sim \chi^2_{k2}$ are independent, with $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ degrees of freedom respectively. We want to show that:

$$E(\frac{X_{1}/k_{1}}{X_{2}/k_{2}}) = E(\frac{1}{X_{2}/k_{2}})$$

So using the independence of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ and the fact that for independent random variables X and Y and some functions on those variables g( ), h( ) we have $E(g(X)*h(Y)) = E(g(X))*E(h(Y))$, we can rewrite:

$$E(\frac{X_{1}/k_{1}}{X_{2}/k_{2}}) = E(\frac{X_{1}}{k_{1}}) E(\frac{1}{\frac{X_{2}}{k_{2}}})$$

Then, using properties of expectation:

$$\frac{1}{k_{1}}E(X_{1})E(\frac{1}{\frac{X_{2}}{k_{2}}})$$

Since $E(X_{1}) = k_{1}$ (property of Chi-Square r.v.), fraction and $E(X_{1})$ cancel out and we obtain the required result:

$$F = E(\frac{1}{\frac{X_{2}}{k_{2}}})$$

We generally can not conclude that $E(F) = 1$, the appropriate argument would be of course to derive the formula for E(F), which is in its difficulty way above the level of Wooldridge's textbook ([E(F) derivation](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/F-distribution)). I think that what the exercise asks us to do, is to state something like: since in this case $E(g(X)) \neq g(E(X))$ (g( ) being some function on random variable X) then we **can not** write something like:
$$E(\frac{1}{\frac{X_{2}}{k_{2}}})= \frac{1}{E(\frac{X_{2}}{k_{2}})} = \frac{1}{E(X_{2}) {\frac{1}{k_2}}} = 1$$
hence $E(F) \neq 1$.